# Show all errors in json schema using json validate using python

Tags: python, json, validation

I am writing a Python code to validate JSON schema but it is not showing all the errors in it , only the first one. Can anyone help to fix the code so that it displays all the errors.
Below is the code:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import sys
import json
import jsonschema
from jsonschema import validate

schema = {
    "type" : "object",
    "properties" : {
        "price" : {"type" : "number"},
        "name" : {"type" : "string"},
    },
}

data = \
[
    { "name": 20, "price": 10},        
]

print("Validating the input data using jsonschema:")
for idx, item in enumerate(data):
    try:
        validate(item, schema)
        sys.stdout.write("Record #{}: OK\n".format(idx))
    except jsonschema.exceptions.ValidationError as ve:
        sys.stderr.write("Record #{}: ERROR\n".format(idx))
        sys.stderr.write(str(ve) + "\n")
```

Comment: That code sample seems to have only one violation.  `data` contains one item, in which `name` is a number instead of a string.  Everything else seems ok.  Do you have another example with more errors?

Comment: Run this with the following data:data = \
[
    { "name": 20, "price": "thirty"},        
]     it will still be showing only one error and not two errors.

Comment: Is it supposed to return all violations, or just the first one it finds?  What does the documentation say?

Comment: Hey @AnandNaidu have you got some working solution?

Answer (score 16):

To get all the validation errors in a single instance, use [iter_errors()](https://python-jsonschema.readthedocs.io/en/stable/validate/#jsonschema.IValidator.iter_errors) method of the validator class.

eg.:

```py
import jsonschema

schema = {
    "type" : "object",
    "properties" : {
        "price" : {"type" : "number"},
        "name" : {"type" : "string"},
    },
}
data = { "name": 20, "price": "ten"}

validator = jsonschema.Draft7Validator(schema)

errors = validator.iter_errors(data)  # get all validation errors

for error in errors:
    print(error)
    print('------')
```

Output:

```
'ten' is not of type 'number'

Failed validating 'type' in schema['properties']['price']:
    {'type': 'number'}

On instance['price']:
    'ten'

------
20 is not of type 'string'

Failed validating 'type' in schema['properties']['name']:
    {'type': 'string'}

On instance['name']:
    20

------
```

The [jsonschema.validate()](https://github.com/Julian/jsonschema/blob/master/jsonschema/validators.py#L932) method chooses the best match error among these by some heuristic and raises it.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `continue` or `pass` in the except block to skip it from quiting after first exception.

Comment: This shouldn't be the problem.  If an exception is handled, as in this example, it doesn't stop processing.

Answer (score 0):

You can collect and return all the errors using the iter_errors method, using validate will only return the first error encountered.

Here's my approach:

```
    try:
    

        doc = self.args_json
        validator = jsonschema.Draft7Validator(self.schema)
        if not validator.is_valid(doc):
            errors = []
            for error in sorted(validator.iter_errors(doc), key=str):
                errors.append(error.message)
            self.finish({
                "valid": False,
                "details": errors
            })
        else:
            self.finish({
                "valid": True
            })
    except jsonschema.exceptions.SchemaError  as exc: #Invalid Schema
        raise HTTPError(400, reason=str(exc))
    except jsonschema.exceptions.ValidationError  as exc: #Invalid Doc
        raise HTTPError(400, reason=str(exc))
```